# How to append all the elements of a list efficiently in R

Tags: r, append

So, I have a list with elements that are integer vectors of variable length... It can be reproduced like this

```
N<-1000
x<-list()
for(i in 1:N){
  x[[i]]<-1:sample.int(10,1)
}
```

But in my case I have a list with a million elements, `N=1.000.000`.

What I need is to append all the elements of the list in order to create a unique vector. I have tried the following methods, all of them extremely slow and in fact never end to run because appending in R is really inefficient.

```
library(abind)
abind(x)
```

also this:

```
y<-integer()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  y<-append(y,x[[i]])
}
```

What do you suggest? The vector will end up having around 10 million values... so maybe R just can't handle this in a normal computer and the only solution is to split the list in various parts?

Comment: Have you tried `unlist(x, use.names=FALSE)`.  `unlist` is reasonably fast, but if the number of list elements are too big, splitting the process may be better

Comment: omg... how can I forget the existence of unlist... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unlist` with `use.names=FALSE` if the `list` elements are named

```
 unlist(x, use.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: alternatives are `rapply(x, c)` and `c(x, recursive=T)` but yours is faster!